# How to run Battle Simulator

Tags: starcraft-2

could you please advise, how to run battle simulator? I've seen post on battle net it should be available and post is quite old, but how can I start it?

I heard there are custom maps searched and found one... on start I have just observer... (i started with Protoss only) and can't figure out how to build units...

I saw how Nany and other streamers do that in much better way, but cannot recall how do they do that.

Maybe I should find the PROPER map?

P.S. In fact, Now I need to check whom marines are targeting when fight with mix of immortals and zealots.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to create a set of units quickly for 2 players and they run a battle with them against 1 AI.

Then you can go to Arqades and find **"HOTS Unit Tester Online" Map** (I can't be sure about other servers, but it is on Europe server and I saw it on American server).

Then it is quite self explanatory, you can change terrain and choose units for both sides, and choose upgrades for them. Also you have help button.

Once you put everything you need you can run it, taking control of one side.